# How color ~code~ on export from org-mode to latex (pdf)?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I am trying to export an org file to latex (to pdf via latex) and to make latex color the inline ~code~ parts.

According to the manual (see [1] "Defining filters for individual files") this should be possible with the following:

```
#+BIND: org-export-filter-code-functions (tmp-latex-code-filter)
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports results :results none
  (defun tmp-latex-code-filter (text backend info)
    "red inline code"
    (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex) 
        (format "{\color{red} %s }" text)))
#+END_SRC
#+latex_header: \usepackage{xcolor}

~this is a test~
```

However, it does not work at all and I cannot seem to pin down the problem.

I have tried to c/p the example from the manual (again see [1]) but this does not work either (it should remove the striked out text).

```
#+BIND: org-export-filter-strike-through-functions (tmp-f-strike-through)
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports results :results none
  (defun tmp-f-strike-through (s backend info) "")
#+END_SRC

~this is a test~

+this is a test+
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve coloring ~code~ when exporting to latex?

Thank you

Edit:
Using the fixed example from your answer, the produced .tex file (minus personal information):

```
% Created 2020-06-10 Wed 00:27
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\hypersetup{
 pdftitle={},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 26.3 (Org mode 9.1.9)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\texttt{this is a test}

\sout{this is a test}
\end{document}
```

It is interesting to me, that it simply works for you. I have tried reinstalling emacs. My emacs was at version 25 before, however, there was no change in the output.

I have also tried it with a clean `init.el` and just org mode enabled and it still does not work for me.

Edit2: 
Here the Emacs and Org mode version outputs

```
GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2019-09-16
Org mode version 9.1.9 (release_9.1.9-65-g5e4542 @ /usr/share/emacs/26.3/lisp/org/)
```

Edit3:
That did the trick, Thank you very much.
I added

```
# -*- org-export-allow-bind-keywords: t -*-
```

as first line in my org file (allowing the `#+BIND` keyword for this file only) and now it works perfectly.

[1] https://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-Export-Configuration.html

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the `.tex` file that is produced? That should provide a fair idea of what is going on.

Comment: Can you also add version information both for your emacs and your Org mode? `C-u M-x emacs-version` and `C-u M-x org-version` will provide that information and insert it into the current buffer, ready for cut-and-pasting it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT/ The `#+BIND:` keyword needs to be turned on as well:

```
(setq org-export-allow-bind-keywords t)
```

I had set that variable and forgotten about it, but the default is nil I think (primarily to protect you from yourself I guess).

The doc string for the variable says:

> Non-nil means BIND keywords can define local variable values.
>   This is a potential security risk, which is why the default value
>   is nil.  You can also allow them through local buffer variables.

The last sentence refers to the [File local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html#File-Variables) mechanism in Emacs.
/EDIT

There is one bug in that backslashes in elisp strings have to be escaped:

```el
  (defun tmp-latex-code-filter (text backend info)
    "red inline code"
    (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex) 
        (format "{\\color{red} %s }" text))
```

but other than that, both of the examples work fine for me - when I export the following to PDF:

```
#+BIND: org-export-filter-strike-through-functions (tmp-f-strike-through)
#+BIND: org-export-filter-code-functions (tmp-latex-code-filter)
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports results :results none
  (defun tmp-latex-code-filter (text backend info)
    "red inline code"
    (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex) 
        (format "{\\color{red} %s }" text)))
#+END_SRC
#+latex_header: \usepackage{xcolor}
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports results :results none
  (defun tmp-f-strike-through (s backend info) "")
#+END_SRC

~this is a test~

+this is a test+
```

I get

[image: cropped PDF output with red text only]

and the (slightly sanitized) tex file looks like this:

```LaTeX
% Created 2020-06-09 Tue 12:54
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\date{\today}
\title{}

\begin{document}

{\color{red} \texttt{this is a test} }
\end{document}
```

Comment: I edited the answer to add info about the `org-export-allow-bind-keywords` variable (which I had forgotten about).